# Move console and logcat view to bottom

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse's（ADT bundle Mac OSX） console view and logcat view are located at the right side of the screen. When activated, they will cover my code editor. （When I maximize them they will automatically move to the bottom, but when minimized they fly back to the right side again.）

status 1:normal ,them cover the editor,[image: normal ,them cover the editor]

status 2:  when I max them, look like good, but
[image: when I max them, look like good, but]

status 3:when minimize them, backto status 1[image: when minimize them, backto status 1]

Comment: I use another eclipse version， which can move logcat/console view to position I want, but can't do it here.

Comment: was the issue ever resolved?

Answer (score 12):

You can click the title of the tab and drag it to a new location (in this case the bottom of the page)

Comment: I do. but when minimize, them back to right again. I used ADT-bundle. I hate this

Comment: @bellnas - Welcome to Eclipse... Learning to use Eclipse is a lot harder than learning Java!

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work. And it seems to work for left and right, but when dragging to the bottom I get new windows despite the drop cursur indicating bottom placement.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but it comes up in the top google results so I thought I'd reply with a solution. I was having the same issue as the OP, even when docking on the bottom of the editor Console was still minimizing to the left side.

I fixed this inadvertently while fixing another annoyance (non re-sizable toolbar sections).

```
Go to Window->Preferences->General->Appearences
Change theme to Windows 7
Restart Eclipse
Dock to bottom of screen and minimize.
```

This worked for me, hope it helps someone else out there.

Comment: Hey, they don't believe my problem, even said I make confuse myself.

Comment: @Jberg I don't see Windows 7 theme in my Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers version 4.13.0

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure it the view is open. Then, click on the Logcat tab and drag it to the bottom of the page. Do this for the Console tab and any other tab that you want at the bottom of the page. Then, minimize them and open them again. They should remain at the bottom of the page. 
It looks like right now you have it in the same pane as where the code normally resides.

Answer (score 3):

Since Eclipse Neon (4.6, June 2016), you don't need to drag each tab individually. You can just drag the empty space after the tabs to move the whole stack of views.

You can do this both when the stack is minimized/maximized and when it's not.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse version 2020-09 (4.17.0), one can reset the display by selecting "Window >> Perspective >> Reset Perspective"

Answer (score 0):

First, minimize the whole output console. Then select the location by single click dragging it down to the bottom of the page & then open it & select it by dragging it from the top in the required area.

Answer (score 0):

Window->Perspective->Reset Prespective will solve that